# How to get all post from a post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to get all product from database with function  `get_post_types`,but i get an empty array:

```
 <?php

   $list=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type='product'");

   if (empty($list)) {
     echo "NONE";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use the standard `WP_Query` method instead:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$product_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $product_query->have_posts() ){
    while( $product_query->have_posts() ){
        $product_query->the_post();
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to display image for each category product

Comment: `<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '10', 'category_name' => single_cat_title('', false)) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

echo '<img src="'C:\xampp\htdocs\cs\wp-content\themes\cs\img\bocal.png'">';

<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: What do u want to pull from database? all products within one category? or all categories? or what?

Comment: yes from database for display image depends product

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$products = get_posts(array(
                            'numberposts'   => -1,
                            'post_type'     => 'product',
                        ));
```

Check that *post_type* name is correct.

This query will get all the post with type *product*, for get only the published ones, add:

```
'post_status' => 'publish'
```

To the array arguments.

From a post you can get a lot of information:
To get the **post image**:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

To get the **category of a post**:

```
$cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

*$cats* is an array of terms.

Comment: I want to display image for each category product

Comment: @boooks are you using some plugin for this?

Comment: @boooks it's already answered, take a look: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155435/woocommerce-query-all-products-and-categories